# Rerunning a set of JUnit tests multiple times

Tags: java, junit

I've got a set of tests that test some timzeone related functionality

I have a Before method that sets the default timezone to one of my choosing, and an after method that restores whatever the default was before the tests.

So I basically want to do

Set timezone to UTC

Run tests

Restore timezone

Set timezone to EST

Run tests

Restore timezone

Set timezone to JST

Run tests

Restore timezone

The tests are identical in each case.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the Parameterized and RunWith notations:

See: http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/writing-a-parameterized-junit-test/

Answer (score 5):

Yup, there is a nice way to do the same test over and over again, just with some other dataset. The solution is "@RunWith(Parameterized.class)" - [link to javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html). I'm assuming you're using JUnit 4 - but TestNG also has such functionality from what I remember.

The code you'll need to write will look somewhat like this:

```
 @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
 public class FibonacciTest {
        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
                return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                                Fibonacci,
                                { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 },
                                                { 6, 8 } } });
        }

        private int fInput;

        private int fExpected;

        public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
                fInput= input;
                fExpected= expected;
        }

        @Test
        public void test(@HeresHowYouGetValue Type value) {
                assertAnswerKey(new Object[][] {
                                Fibonacci,
                                { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 },
                                                { 6, 8 } } });
                assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post I wrote that shows several ways of running the tests repeatedly with code examples:
http://codehowtos.blogspot.com/2011/04/run-junit-test-repeatedly.html

You can use the @Parametrized runner, or use the special runner included in the post

Answer (score 0):

recently I created [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) project. you may find it useful. it lets you write:

```
@TestWith({
   "EST",
   "UTC",
   "null"
})
public void testMethod(TimeZone timeZone) {
   setTimeZone(timeZone);
   ...
}

@After
public void restoreTimezone() {
  ...
}
```